# How can I avoid CS:GO servers loaded with bots?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I find that a lot of times, when using Community Quick Play, I end up being pushed into a server with many bots, and no real players.

Playing a game using "Find a Game" works fine, but Community Quickplay is one I frequent the most.

How can avoid these bot-ridden servers?

Comment: You could filter servers with the tag "bots" for starters. Not all include this tag though, but it is a good start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real way to avoid getting into games with bots when you use the quickplay/matchmaking options.  Browsing for games manually is the only way to assure you get into a game with real people (or playing competitive).

Comment: +1 to Brian, however if someone leaves a competitive match, you still would be playing with a bot.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of agree with the other people. You pretty much NEED to either manually go through the games to get in a server with challenging real people or get in game with dogwater bots. They should soon add an option in which it says if we want bots or not. Like if we are trying to practice aim then we can turn it on, If we are trying to do a challenge or face real people, We turn it off.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).