# How can I disable bots and play one on one with a friend?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Is there a way to play a 1:1 match without getting filled up with bots?

My friend and I would like to boost a couple of achievements, but the bots always prevent that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid CS:GO servers loaded with bots?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115391/how-can-i-avoid-csgo-servers-loaded-with-bots)

Comment: Are you running a server yourself?

Comment: @5pike i don't think its a duplicate, the other person was referring to matchmaking and ending up in a game filled with bots. Here OP is asking about how to create a game without having it filled with bots (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @WizLiz - we don't know that yet. OP hasn't clarified if he is running a server or just uses matchmaking.

Comment: Matchmaking or not, it's still the same question. There's no reason making two questions for the same problem even in one case you run the server yourself and in the other you're looking for one.

Comment: @3ventic I'm not sure I agree. Searching for a server with no bots is surely different from configuring your own server to use no bots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to play 1on1 you have to use your own server or an empty server online without bots.
Because you need to have admin rights to use the commands for the bot configuration.

Open your console on your own server and use the following commands to disable, freeze or let bots only use knifes to practise your shooting skills.

bot configurations :

- bot_quota 0    (normal is 10 , so you remove them)
- bot_kick  - to kick all bots
- bot_stop 1   - let them stop, freezed
- bot_knives_only 1 - bots use knifes only

Remember if you do not host the server locally, you need to use rcon. If you've purchased/rented your server somewhere, you can find it in the server.cfg file, or on the provider's control panel.

Usage: `rcon_password PASSWORD`

Example if I had the password "hello": `rcon_password hello`

You need to execute the command above first. Afterwards you need to execute the initial commands like so: rcon bot_quota 0

Comment: Is that not possible by just hosting a game instead of just installing the full server package? I tried "Play with friends", but we always get bots in there.

Comment: yes of course you can simply host a game as well.